# How to make cheat sheets in Latex?

Tags: latex

I want to make cheat sheets for my personal use. I want to use this opportunity to get a good hand on [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) too. (I am already comfortable making simple documents math related in LaTeX.)

Now I want to try making cheat sheets in LaTeX. But I don't know how to do it. In cheat sheets, usually the page is split into multiple rectangular sections and each one has a few commands or notes inside it. Each rectangular section has a border etc.

How can it be done in LaTeX? Are any packages available to do this? Do you think [TikZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) will be a good idea for this?

Comment: On a side note I would recommend lyx for creating latex documents -- you won't need a cheat sheet if you use this software.

Comment: Or, by the time you've done a good job by hand, you won't need the sheet anymore...

Comment: Good point, but you could use the time and brain-space for more useful stuff :D like proof-reading, or drawing pretty diagrams :D

Comment: BTW, ajay, why make a question like this community wiki?

Comment: I am fed up of people trying to close a question. So, my general policy is to always make it a Wiki. I don't care what the category is, personally.

Comment: Yeh the 3k'ers are a bit gung-ho with their new-found powers :P

Comment: CW will not save you from a deserved closing, and the lack of it should not result in the closing of good questions. It generally will only matter in marginal cases.

Comment: The [baposter template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/baposter-landscape-poster) looks right for this needs. The templates features much of what is need. It is worth to look at.

Comment: This question does exist now on tex.stackexchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99765/8666

Answer (score 68):

Because some professors allowed us to use cheat sheets written on a computer for exams, I decided to create a template some time ago to save enough space as possible but keep readibility. The template uses the code of the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218587/how-to-set-one-header-for-each-page-using-multicols).

**Update:** The complete source code can now be found [here](https://github.com/kenfehling/latex-cheatsheet).

The base file looks like this:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows,fit,calc,graphs,graphs.standard}
\usepackage[nosf]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[t1]{sourcesanspro}
%\usepackage[lf]{MyriadPro}
%\usepackage[lf,minionint]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[top=0mm,bottom=1mm,left=0mm,right=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{microtype}

\let\bar\overline

\definecolor{myblue}{cmyk}{1,.72,0,.38}

\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{myblue}
\colorlet{circle area}{myblue!5}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
    outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}
    
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath \color{myblue}}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay \color{myblue}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.8}
\pagestyle{empty}

\global\mdfdefinestyle{header}{%
linecolor=gray,linewidth=1pt,%
leftmargin=0mm,rightmargin=0mm,skipbelow=0mm,skipabove=0mm,
}

\newcommand{\header}{
\begin{mdframed}[style=header]
\footnotesize
\sffamily
Cheat sheet\\
by~Your~Name,~page~\thepage~of~2
\end{mdframed}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
                                {.2ex}%
                                {.2ex}%x
                                {\color{myblue}\sffamily\small\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{1}{0mm}%
                                {.2ex}%
                                {.2ex}%x
                                {\sffamily\bfseries}}



\def\multi@column@out{%
   \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@M
   \speci@ls \else
   \ifvoid\colbreak@box\else
     \mult@info\@ne{Re-adding forced
               break(s) for splitting}%
     \setbox\@cclv\vbox{%
        \unvbox\colbreak@box
        \penalty-\@Mv\unvbox\@cclv}%
   \fi
   \splittopskip\topskip
   \splitmaxdepth\maxdepth
   \dimen@\@colroom
   \divide\skip\footins\col@number
   \ifvoid\footins \else
      \leave@mult@footins
   \fi
   \let\ifshr@kingsaved\ifshr@king
   \ifvbox \@kludgeins
     \advance \dimen@ -\ht\@kludgeins
     \ifdim \wd\@kludgeins>\z@
        \shr@nkingtrue
     \fi
   \fi
   \process@cols\mult@gfirstbox{%
%%%%% START CHANGE
\ifnum\count@=\numexpr\mult@rightbox+2\relax
          \setbox\count@\vsplit\@cclv to \dimexpr \dimen@-1cm\relax
\setbox\count@\vbox to \dimen@{\vbox to 1cm{\header}\unvbox\count@\vss}%
\else
      \setbox\count@\vsplit\@cclv to \dimen@
\fi
%%%%% END CHANGE
            \set@keptmarks
            \setbox\count@
                 \vbox to\dimen@
                  {\unvbox\count@
                   \remove@discardable@items
                   \ifshr@nking\vfill\fi}%
           }%
   \setbox\mult@rightbox
       \vsplit\@cclv to\dimen@
   \set@keptmarks
   \setbox\mult@rightbox\vbox to\dimen@
          {\unvbox\mult@rightbox
           \remove@discardable@items
           \ifshr@nking\vfill\fi}%
   \let\ifshr@king\ifshr@kingsaved
   \ifvoid\@cclv \else
       \unvbox\@cclv
       \ifnum\outputpenalty=\@M
       \else
          \penalty\outputpenalty
       \fi
       \ifvoid\footins\else
         \PackageWarning{multicol}%
          {I moved some lines to
           the next page.\MessageBreak
           Footnotes on page
           \thepage\space might be wrong}%
       \fi
       \ifnum \c@tracingmulticols>\thr@@
                    \hrule\allowbreak \fi
   \fi
   \ifx\@empty\kept@firstmark
      \let\firstmark\kept@topmark
      \let\botmark\kept@topmark
   \else
      \let\firstmark\kept@firstmark
      \let\botmark\kept@botmark
   \fi
   \let\topmark\kept@topmark
   \mult@info\tw@
        {Use kept top mark:\MessageBreak
          \meaning\kept@topmark
         \MessageBreak
         Use kept first mark:\MessageBreak
          \meaning\kept@firstmark
        \MessageBreak
         Use kept bot mark:\MessageBreak
          \meaning\kept@botmark
        \MessageBreak
         Produce first mark:\MessageBreak
          \meaning\firstmark
        \MessageBreak
        Produce bot mark:\MessageBreak
          \meaning\botmark
         \@gobbletwo}%
   \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\partial@page
                      \page@sofar}%
   \@makecol\@outputpage
     \global\let\kept@topmark\botmark
     \global\let\kept@firstmark\@empty
     \global\let\kept@botmark\@empty
     \mult@info\tw@
        {(Re)Init top mark:\MessageBreak
         \meaning\kept@topmark
         \@gobbletwo}%
   \global\@colroom\@colht
   \global \@mparbottom \z@
   \process@deferreds
   \@whilesw\if@fcolmade\fi{\@outputpage
      \global\@colroom\@colht
      \process@deferreds}%
   \mult@info\@ne
     {Colroom:\MessageBreak
      \the\@colht\space
              after float space removed
              = \the\@colroom \@gobble}%
    \set@mult@vsize \global
  \fi}

\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\small
\begin{multicols*}{5}
\input{section1}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

When you use the code copy the template and put your `LaTeX` code in external files like `section1.tex, section2.tex,...`. Than you can easily follow the normal structure inside these `LaTeX` files like

```tex
\section{Title of section 1}
\subsection*{Title of subsection 1}
Some text...
\subsection*{Title of subsection 2}
With some colored math $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i$.
Inserting an image also works:\\
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{yourimage.png}
```

After filling your sections you'll get a much compressed document which still looks good like this:

[image: Cheat sheet page 1]

[image: Cheat sheet page 2]

Comment: How did you get the formulas to be written so compactly?

Comment: I think the code above is the same I used, with the difference that I used `MinionPro` as serif+math and `MyriadPro` as text but both packages are replaced appropriate. LaTeX will automatically compress the document that compact only if you have enough text written. You can try it by filling it with a `lipsum` text. If that wont solve it, I can look for the actual source code with text and graphics.

Comment: But if you just meant "how to get them inline", than the answer is use `$\alpha_1$` instead of `$$\alpha_1$$` for math mode.

Comment: Yes, filling the .tex file with text made latex compress it. Thanks

Comment: It looks super good! Do you mind sharing the .tex files for the individual sections? @Tim

Comment: @PeterH. I uploaded the source code and added the link in the post above.

Comment: By adding `\raggedcolumns` the document will not force all the columns to be the same length. It helped me avoid a lot of  unnecessary blank space in my cheat sheet.

Comment: Link to GitHub is dead by now. archive.org has a snapshot, but not of the actual files ... fixed.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It just outputs a blank page if there is little text. If I `lipsum` 100 paragraphs, it just shows a bunch of text in only the 5th column of all pages. Any idea what could be wrong in my setup? I tried to simply compile a fresh clone of the linked repo, and there is just text in the 5th column.

Answer (score 14):

I've been making my own cheat sheets as well for various things. I really like how the Latex cheat sheet [found here](http://wch.github.io/latexsheet/) looks. I suggest grabbing the tex source and stealing some ideas from it :).

Comment: Unfortunately the link died in the meantime.

Comment: [According to the Internet Archive wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304111720/http://www.stdout.org/~winston/latex/), the link is now at http://wch.github.io/latexsheet/

Answer (score 12):

Consider using [`multicol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol).

And consider familiarizing yourself with [CTAN](https://tug.ctan.org/). Most things TeX end up there sooner or later, though it does require some digging if you don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: The `multicol` link is broken

Answer (score 11):

Here is a beautiful example of a cheat sheet (is a booklet actually, not just a couple of pages).

http://clqr.boundp.org/index.html

It is made using LaTex. It summarizes all the symbols on the Common Lisp Standard.  Maybe you can pick up one or two tips from the available LaTeX source.

Answer (score 8):

I like how these cheat sheets look like:

http://michaelgoerz.net/refcards/